# Notify developer that the file got overwritten

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

We are using Microsoft Team foundation server for version control where multiple developers are working on a branch and check in and check out the code.

How can a developer A be notified via email or SMS that his code got overwritten during the checkin by developer B.

Developer A needs to know this ASAP because the code changes of developer A will not work when its deployed into QA.

We are tring to save time in a fast paced development environment and trying to avoid code overwrite issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to allow continuous parallel development and prevent a checkin from one person breaking the code of others, is to use a CI server. TFS supports this through Team Build.

Though it's preferred to run  team build on a dedicated build server, it can be installed side-by-side on your main TFS server and it's possible to install the Controller component centrally and use your developer's workstations as agents.

There are two types of build triggers that can help you out here:

1. Continuous Integration - this triggers a build of all code directly after every checkin. It will tell you quickly that something did not compile. If you are doing unit tests it can even run these and tell you that a test is failing.
2. Gated - this will force a developer to shelve his code and will only check in the code when the build of the latest version plus the changes in the shelveset succeed. This may seem even better, as the code in source control will never be in a broken state, but in reality I prefer the ci trigger. The main reason for that us that Gated builds can't happen in parallel (due to their nature) and can actually delay the notification that the code is broken.

You can easily configure email alerts through webaccess on specific build outcomes. You can also configure alerts on source changes, but there is no option to only warn people who have edited these specific files before.

You can also run the Build Notification tool from the task tray to show a notification in Windows.

Though this will not tell the person whose code has just been overwritten that it's no longer working, it will tell the person I rewriting that code that he should pay more attention when checking in ;).

Of course you can configure a team alert that notifies everyone when the build breaks (as that's generally called), and there are funny ways to show the build status through small apps like "[siren of shame](http://sirenofshame.com/)", which provides a build monitor service that can be connected to a USB alarm-light that turns on and provides noise whenever someone does something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to avoid this problem during check-in & merge, then I would recommend disabling multiple check-out. This allows file to only be checked out one-at-a-time and can prevent confusion on team projects.

If you need to do farther down the line, you can create TFS Alerts when any code is checked in and sent out to a distribution list, but it would not notify when specific contributions from a specific developer is altered - only a list of altered files during the check-in.

Comment: Though a workable solution, it generally slows down development, instead if speeding je up.