# Code review in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, resharper, azure-pipelines, stylecop

I am new in configuration of TFS.

Currently our project is 50% done but we found that we have very bad code. We consider the need for static code analysis like Resharper or another product like StyleCop, CodeAnalysis and FxCop.

We want configure the TFS to reject a checkin when that check in contains code that triggers code analysis warnings.

But for the previous code we want to suppress the existing warning to prevent the code from becoming worse than it already is.

Comment: Static code analyses will not solve your base problem: communication with the rest of the team that is submitting the code. Talk to that people, they are not aliens. Train them, lead them, commend the for good work, blame for lousy one. ReSharper can not do anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ivan mentions, your root cause it not in the lack of analysis tools, but probably in the level of quality and rigor agreed (or currently being enforeced between team members) between the development team and their project's sponsor. It may be that the pressure on the team is too high, causing important review actions to be skipped, or that the team (or the sponsor!) doesn't have the same desire to quality as you or the sponsor. Or that the team doesn't have the right level of knowledge to prevent these issues from happening.

The best way out of this is to fix as much as you can in a short period of time.

> **Warning**: I've experienced with a number of teams the effect of turning on too many rules all at once. Generally, there is a reluctance for people to concede that their work hasn't been up to par and turning on rules that do not directly cause bug ("The identifier is cased incorrectly" for example) can cause frustration that can severely hamper your momentum. Carefully selecting which rules need to be solved now and which can wait for later worked much better in my experience. Once the team has developed a way to solve these kinds of problem, you can easily apply more.

Turning on Tools like [configuring Code Analysis for your solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264897.aspx) or using the Solution Wide Analysis feature of Resharper, can help you spot issues, but it won't solve them or prevent similar issues from popping up in the future unless your team stops creating them.

> **Tip**: Note that you can turn on Resharper during your build as well [using the Resharper CLI features](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/07/enabling-resharper-cli-in-team-build.html).

StyleCop I would not enforce on this team (just yet) if the code itself is bad enough to trigger massive warnings that may hold bugs and issues. Fix these problems first, make the code it pretty later. Your priorities are now to remove any possible bugs.

CodeAnalysis and FxCop are the same things, so you won't need to turn on both. A tool like Resharper can help your developers to quickly remove a lot of the issues by using the magic-key <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

If you want to create a clean baseline you can run code analysis once, then select all warnings that are generated and then select <kbd>Suppress in global suppression file</kbd>. This will work for Code Analysis issues, but won't suppress any Compiler Warnings, there is no easy way to quickly suppress all current compiler warnings.

> **Tip**: It sometimes helps to temporarily rename any existing `globalsupressions.cs` files, so that this "baseline" is stored separately. You then know which warnings you'll have to fix at a later point in time.
>
> **Tip**: When a developer suppresses a warning, have them add a `Justification="Reason for suppression"` to the suppression that is generated, that way you can distinguish between carefully considered suppression and temporary ones.

Depending on whether you already have a build server your next step is to [install Team Build](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee259687.aspx) and once you have a build server you'll need to [setup a Build Definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631.aspx). This [blog post covers most of the steps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2011/04/06/preventing-check-ins-to-tfs-that-contain-code-analysis-warnings.aspx).

In the build definition set the trigger to "Gated Checkin" and on the Process tab make sure you set Code Analysis to "Always". [If you want to fail your build based on Code Analysis errors, you need to create a custom ruleset and configure that for your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14369929/736079).

To have compiler errors fail the build you can also enable the "Treat Warnings as Errors

Once you have enabled your gated check-in build all developers changes will be prompted to wait for their build to finish. [You can turn on alerts (using Web access) or use the Build Notification Tool to get notified when the changes were successfully submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266762/notify-develper-that-the-file-got-overwritten/30268072#30268072).

> **Tip**: Instead of turning on all rules at once (or switching them all to cause an ERROR during builds) you can also opt to turn on rules a couple at a time and fix them. Turning on rules by category gives you a nice opportunity to teach people the importance of the rules being turned on and possible solutions for fixing them.

A far more advanced solution would be to install and configure SonarQube alongside your Team Build environment. [The ALM Rangers and Sonar have recently worked together to create installation guidance and a number of extensions to enable Team Build and SonarQube integration](http://www.sonarqube.org/announcing-sonarqube-integration-with-msbuild-and-team-build/). You can [find the installation guide here](https://vsarguidance.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1452516).